# C# Serial Port received data is shattered

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have some issue with Serial Port ReceiveData handler. It is being triggered more than once and it splits the data. Here is the Serial Port's settings:

```
            RadioDeviceObject = new RadioDevice();
            RadioDeviceObject.BaudRate = RadioPortBaudRate;
            RadioDeviceObject.PortName = RadioPortName;
            RadioDeviceObject.Parity = System.IO.Ports.Parity.None;
            RadioDeviceObject.DataBits = 8;
            RadioDeviceObject.StopBits = System.IO.Ports.StopBits.One;
            RadioDeviceObject.Handshake = System.IO.Ports.Handshake.None;
            RadioDeviceObject.ReadTimeout = 1000;
            RadioDeviceObject.WriteTimeout = 100;
            RadioDeviceObject.ReceivedBytesThreshold = 1;
            RadioDeviceObject.DataReceived += RadioDeviceObject_DataReceived;
            RadioDeviceObject.Open();
```

I have no idea what is going on and it blocks me to analyze the received data. I checked it on other software, like Termite and Docklight and there is no issue.

Here is what I send/receive:

```
2017-05-22 03:24:56: Sent: 0 0 0 2 236 6 246 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 11 0 
2017-05-22 03:24:56: Received: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 11 
2017-05-22 03:24:56: Received: 16 236 6 246 5 54 54 54 54 63 63 63
```

Comment: How do you send the data? from a µController or another computer?

Comment: It is entirely normal.  Serial ports only handle a single byte as a unit of data, they know nothing whatsoever about a "packet".  Since they are usually quite slow, you normally only get 1 or 2 bytes at a time.  A terminal emulator simply makes this invisible, you can't tell how many reads were used to make a line of text on the screen.  You need a protocol to group a set of bytes into a "packet".  The data is too random to discern a pattern that resembles a protocol, maybe it always transmits a fixed number of bytes as a response so you can simply count them.